# Confusion about Huygens Principle

Tags: optics, waves, visible-light, interference, huygens-principle

According to Huygens Principle, the direction of propagation of waves will be perpendicular to the wavefronts. But I have Confusion in Fraunhofer's Diffraction due to Single Slit. Have a look in the diagram

[image]

Aren't the waves breaking the principles here as the angles are not perpendicular to the wavefronts when the waves Interfere.

[image]

**If the waves will be like this then It will never interfere and we will never get Fringes** I am not getting where i am going wrong? Please Someone explain...

Comment: Fraunhofer's diffraction is in the infinite distance limit. Your circular waves become plane waves and are therefore perpendicular to parallel rays leaving the slit.

Comment: An addition to the comment by @lpz:  The rays converge to a point on a screen when a lens is placed after the slit.

Comment: Your bottom-right sketch displays only two rays, each originating at an edge of the slit.  This is a simplification that ignores essential features:  1) the rays that originate at the edges propagate in *all* forward directions and 2) it ignores the rays originating in the slit ... *between* the edges.  "... everything should be as simple as it can be but not simpler!"   --Roger Sessions, paraphrasing a more involved statement of Einstein.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two different “pictures” of diffraction.

**1st picture**: The propagating field (due, in fact, to Huygens principle) behaves as if each point of the slit emitted spherical waves which then interfere producing the diffraction pattern. When computing the disturbance on the screen, you are considering these spherical waves coming from every source point, and the two rays which you drew, that are not perpendicular to wavefronts, are the paths travelled by the spherical waves.

**2nd picture**: The above is not in contradiction with the usual picture of Huygens principle, which describes how the “next” wavefront is generated from the “previous” one, that is, it ignores the original source and cares only about the wavefront$^1$. 
The wavefront propagates perpendicularly to itself, but in doing so every next wavefront receives contributions from many points of the previous one, in such a way that after some time the entire wavefront will contain information coming from all the source points. It is therefore wrong to think that the *light* only propagates perpendicularly to the wavefront: it is, once again, the wavefront that travels perpendicularly to itself.

I hope that this rather hand-wavy explanation is sufficient, otherwise I will try to be more precise.

---

$^1$This may cause further confusion since in the beginning we do exactly that - ignore what happens before the slit and consider *it* as a source. However, we are doing it once, whereas in the second picture we are applying Huygens principle to every wavefront downstream with respect to the slit.

Comment: "Each point of the source (slit) emits spherical waves ..." be careful with your wording.  There is nothing between the edges that emit anything.  The downstream field can be calculated *as if* points in the slit emit radiation.   Huygens' principle does not claim to describe the mechanism for the creation of the downstream field.